# Force users of a specific devices to install a particular version on Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

We have an app on the Google play store with two version of the APK for different architectures (ARM and x86). This is due to a dependant library being more stable when run natively.

However, a certain x86 based device is failing when running the x86 binary and I would like users of this device to switch to using the ARM version. The options to exclude devices only seems to apply to both APK files together.

Is this possible to configure in the Google Play Developer Console?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found is a hack.

It's possible to add additional contraits to the x86 build as specified here:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html#other-filters

In our case, we can add a constraint on `compatible-screens` to the app manifest saying that the x86 build is only supported by the precise screen resolution of the device that works with the build. The problematic x86 devices have a different resolution and are then excluded.